# domain does not appear on google

Tags: .htaccess, dns, google-search

I noticed that the domain www.adamfresh.it, absolutely not appear on Google.
I think the problem is in my .htaccess.
These are the rules that I applied, they give problems?

```
ErrorDocument 404 /page-not-found
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteBase /

RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^admin - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^captcha - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^ckfinder - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^class - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^control - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^css - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^fancy - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^fancybox - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^FlexSlider - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^font - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^images - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^img - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^include - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^js - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^mail - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^phpmailer - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^require - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^script_js - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^template - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^checkout.php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^end_transaction.php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^index.php - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^html - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^paypal - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^keyclient - [L,NC]



# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# If the request is not for a valid link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
```

Can someone explain?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From here (Switzerland), I just can see "Language not found" in your home page...
It's not a problem with RewriteEngine I think.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think that it is  problem with your .htaccess.

To be on google you need to register your site:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/submit-url